# Remote Desktop Linux to Linux

Tags: ssh, remote

I'm a new user and recently I installed Debian Wheezy in PCs. I'm in charge of a computer center in a public school, and I need a software which control another ones. The trouble is I have been finding one which control "Linux to Linux", not "Linux to Windows". In youtube only appears videos about SSH terminal mode and Linux to Windows.

All machines have Debian wheezy and my pc desktop has Ubuntu 14.04. I need to know what my students are doing, and to have a better control over those machines.

Comment: There are solutions for Ubuntu, but I don't know about Debian. I think you need to ask on [unix.se].

Comment: Also see: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/remote-administration.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install a VNC server on every other computer, for example `vino-server`, and a VNC client on your computer, for example, `vinagre`.

The programs mentioned above are known to cooperate perfectly together.  You can find both of them in the Ubuntu repos and I'm pretty sure you will find them in the Debian repos too since they are quite old and reliable apps.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a program called TeamViewer to access the desktop. It's really useful - especially if you set it to open on login. If you just need terminal just use `ssh`